# Part of my code is "not defined" when I try and use a lower part of the code

Tags: python

When I try and open Flamma by entering `2`, it states that `Tetraites is not defined`. I believe it is to do with the organisation of my code, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
import time
Intro = open('#Intro.txt', mode='r')
for line in Intro:
     line = line.replace("\n","")
     print(line)
name = input("Which gladiator do you choose? (use the numbers before the name): ")


if name == '1':
    Tetraites = open('1 Tetraites.txt', mode='r')
for line in Tetraites:
     line = line.replace("\n","")
     print(line)
if name == "2":
       Flamma = open('2 Flamma.txt', mode='r')
for line in Flamma:
     line = line.replace("\n","")
     print(line)
if name == "3":
    Verus = open('3 Verus.txt', mode='r')
for line in Verus:
     line = line.replace("\n","")
     print(line)
```

Traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "/Volumes/Data/Users/david.twohill/Desktop/python/choose adventure/Adventure.py", line 14, in  for line in Tetraites: NameError: name 'Tetraites' is not defined

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Data/Users/david.twohill/Desktop/python/choose adventure/Adventure.py", line 14, in <module>
    for line in Tetraites:
NameError: name 'Tetraites' is not defined

Comment: your indentation is way off

Comment: Well you defined `Tetraites` in the scope of an `if` block so it's not visible outside of that scope

Comment: Note that you have huge amounts of repetition - why not store the file names in a dictionary, e.g. `filenames = {'1': '1 Tetraites.txt', ...}`?

Comment: One: Fix you code indent. Two: use `with open('2 Flamma.txt', mode='r') as f: print(''.join(f.readlines()))` instead these `for`.

Comment: @KevinGuan: `''.join(f.readlines())` doesn't do what you think it does, since `file.readlines()` retains the newlines. So `''.join(f.readlines())` produces the same string as `f.read()`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Oops, sorry about that. What about `with open('file', 'r') as f: f.read().replace('\n', '')`?

Comment: @KevinGuan there's nothing wrong with that part of the OP's code (aside from that it's repeated). `.strip()` is neater if they don't mind losing other leading and trailing whitespace, but otherwise the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @KevinGuan: I suspect that David just wants to print the file data without double-spacing, so he can do `print(f.read())`. Or to do it in a loop, `for line in f: print(line, end='')`, with perhaps an extra `print()` when the loop ends.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know, this just a tip. But maybe PM2Ring is right. If OP just want to print the data of the file without double-spacing, I'll recommend using `f.read()`

Comment: @PM2Ring Hmm...I agree with you.

Comment: @DavidTwohill: You should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) naltipar's answer to indicate that your question has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your code's indentation. Please take a look at this code segment:

```
if name == '1':
    Tetraites = open('1 Tetraites.txt', mode='r')
for line in Tetraites:
    line = line.replace("\n","")
    print(line)
```

`Tetraites` is defined inside the if statement, but since you have give `2` as an input, it never gets defined, but then the `for` loop tries to access it.

Please change the code's indentation like so:

```
if name == '1':
    Tetraites = open('1 Tetraites.txt', mode='r')
    for line in Tetraites:
        line = line.replace("\n","")
        print(line)
elif name == "2":
    Flamma = open('2 Flamma.txt', mode='r')
    for line in Flamma:
        line = line.replace("\n","")
        print(line)
elif name == "3":
    Verus = open('3 Verus.txt', mode='r')
    for line in Verus:
        line = line.replace("\n","")
        print(line)
```

Comment: That does fix the problem. OTOH, it would be better to [avoid the repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 1):

naltipar has shown you how to fix the error you were getting due to bad indentation. But here's a more compact way to organize your code.

An important principle in coding is [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). This not only keeps your code shorter and easier to read, it also makes it easier to make modifications.

When experienced coders are reading other people's code and we see repeated blocks we have to slow down to check that the code blocks really *are* repeated and that there aren't some subtle variations. And then we wonder *why* are those code blocks being repeated. :)

Unnecessary repetition of code blocks makes it easy to accidentally introduce a minor error in one (or more) of the blocks. And that can lead to bugs that are hard to track down since it can be hard to tell which blocks are correct and which are faulty.

I've used jonrsharpe's suggestion to store the gladiator info files in a dictionary; I've also added a `while` loop to make sure we get a valid gladiator number string from the user.

```
def print_file(fname, 'r'):
    with open(fname) as f:
        print(f.read())

gladiator_filenames = {
    '1': '1 Tetraites.txt',
    '2': '2 Flamma.txt',
    '3': '3 Verus.txt',
}

print_file('#Intro.txt')

prompt = "Which gladiator do you choose? (use the numbers before the name): "

#Loop until we get a valid number string
while True:
    numstring = input(prompt)
    fname = gladiator_filenames.get(numstring)
    if fname is None:
        print("Unknown gladiator number!")
    else:
        break

print_file(fname)
```

Comment: I should have included such a tip in my own answer, anyway I am upvoting this as a complementary answer.

Comment: @naltipar: Thanks! I've already upvoted your's and hopefully David will accept it.